# Can’t import Blaze compiled HTML from relative path

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

In my templates folder I have one js file where I’m trying to `import "./start_page.html"`, Meteor crashes and gives the following error: Cannot find module `./start_page.html` even though the html file is in the same directory.

The code in the `start_page.js` only works if it’s in `client/main.js`. I’m thinking that the problem maybe is in the `Router.js` code or `client/main.js`. I’ve tried importing the `start_page.js` in the other files to see if the error goes away but no luck.

start_page.html:

```
 <template name="start_page">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg schedule">Test 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg status">Test 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

start_page.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './start_page.html';
Template.start_page.events({
    'click .schedule'(event){
        alert("test");
    },
});
```

Router.js:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: "index",
    action: function() {
    console.log('start page');
    BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {content: "start_page"});
    }
});


// for the / page
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: "index",
    action: function() {
    console.log('guest home route');
    BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {content: "guest_home"});
    }
});
```

My directory structure is currently like this:

```
client/
  main.css
  main.html
  main.js
  routes.js
server/
  main.js
shared/
 shared.js
templates/
  start_page.html
  start_page.js
  template.html
  template2.html
  template3.html
```

Comment: The cannot find module error also occurs sometimes when there is some syntax error in the HTML or handlebars code of the template.

Comment: My template looks good to me.

Comment: Have you tried importing 'start_page.js' in 'client/routes.js' ? Also, is your 'mainLayout ' setup correctly?